# Spring MVC + my own security model

Tags: security, spring-mvc

Is it possible to work with spring mvc and implement my own end to end security.
 1. How do i set the session?
 2. How can I map the areas that meeds permissions (On every controller entry point?)?

Please give me some points about it
**(I know that the "V" button at the left will reword you with points even though i am new)**

**Edit**
Since I cant find a good example of how to implement it with existing database, and existing roles, i have decided to do it in my own because it would be simple anyway.

Thanls

Comment: Could you mention why you want to write your own security instead of using Spring Security?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you intend for your application to be used in any kind of production environment, I would highly recommend not writing your own security implementation for a web application.

Even if you have an existing database schema for users and roles, it would be much easier to spend some time working out how to make it work with Spring Security than to write your own. Security is a complex topic and its important to get it right in a production application.

Comment: Well I guess there is no other way

Answer (score 0):

1) This is not a problem to get session.

```
    @RequestMapping(value="/signin",method = RequestMethod.POST)
          public ModelAndView loginUser(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response){ 

    //and then you can work with session where ever you want.
    //    
    }

  @RequestMapping(value="/doSomethinng",method = RequestMethod.POST)
          public ModelAndView doSomething(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response){ 

   //check with session if user is authenticated. 
    }
```

Hope it help.